# Azure Data Studio - fail to connection to login to server

Tags: azure, localhost, connection-string, azure-data-studio

I have create a container with docker:

mssql is in docker with status up

```
> docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd!12" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I am trying to connect to SQL server on my network with Azure Data Studio, and I am getting error:

*Login failed for user 'sa'.*

Details for the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<CreateReplaceConnectionContinuation>b__0(Task`1 _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<OpenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 312
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line 666
ClientConnectionId:7f82dc23-5d48-4820-9f58-4ccf08416472
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
```

I have asked and tried to restart the container. I also type the pwd again multiple times and even try to create new container in Docker, but failed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ6up.png)

please help...and thank you.

Try: enter the pwd again and again - create new container - restart container

Expected: it will sucessfully login to localhost server

Result: still failed to log in

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to see what the error logs are in the container,

```
docker logs [your container id]
```

If you see an error message like,

> Error: The evaluation period has expired.
>
> /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 104

Try to pull the docker image again,

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Comment: I have found the reason by changing the password and enabling login in the Security tab in SQL Server Management Studio ^^. But thanks again for your solution